# compose a javascript expression that has one uppecase letter and six numbers

Tags: php, javascript, regex, forms, expression-web

I need to compose a regular JavaScript expression. This expression is based on a serial number The parameters of the expression is this:

One Uppercase Letter at the beginning and the rest of the expression is digits (6)

Example: E234585, C345678, E001234

Thanks for your assistance

Comment: Do you want to match these? or capture them? please add more info describing what you want to do with the regex, or if you meant that you want to generate strings like "XNNNNNNN" then you're asking the wrong question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this expression:

`/^[A-Z]\d{6}$/`

This will match serial numbers in the format you described.

`[A-Z]` matches the first uppercase letter, then `\d{6}` matches the following 6 digits. The [anchors](http://www.regular-expressions.info/anchors.html) (`^` and `$`) ensure the matched string contains only the serial number and nothing else.

Comment: don't forget to explain the anchors, too!

Comment: Thanks. I think it's pretty thorough now. :P

Comment: Hello, Thanks for the answer ahl18. The expression you provided was ideal. I really appreciate the prompt responses.

Comment: @user1555523 You're welcome! I'd appreciate it if you would accept my answer by giving me the giant green checkmark! :)

Answer (score 1):

Your question is very unclear, I'm going to take a stab in the dark and assume you meant you wanted to generate those random strings:

```
var getRandomInt = function (min, max) {
    return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1)) + min;  
};

var getRandomLetter = function () {
    return String.fromCharCode(getRandomInt(65, 90));
};

var getRandomDigit = function () {
    return getRandomInt(0, 9);
};

var yourString = getRandomLetter() + getRandomDigit() + ... + getRandomDigit();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
​var serialre = new RegExp('[A-Z]{1}[0-9]{6}');​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​

if(serialre.test('A123456')){
       document.write('yep');
} else {
    document.write('nope');
}

document.write('<br />');    

if(serialre.test('POOPSTAINS!')){
       document.write('yep');
} else {
    document.write('nope');
}
​
```

Produces:

```
yep
nope
```

Check out the [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ztzP2/)